# Prove convergence of $\int^{\infty}_{0}\ t^{z-1}cos(t)dt$ and $\int^{\infty}_{0}\ t^{z-1}sin(t)dt$

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, analyticity, trigonometric-series

For a complex analysis problem set I am trying to show that the integrals

$$\int^{\infty}_{0}\ t^{z-1}cos(t)dt \quad and \quad \int^{\infty}_{0}\ t^{z-1}sin(t)dt $$

is convergent for $0<Re(z)<1$ and $-1<Re(z)<1$ respectively, but am unsure of how to progress. I've tried expressing $cos(t)$ and $sin(t)$ as a Taylor series, and also expressing the integrals as shown below,

$$\int^{\infty}_{0}\ t^{z-1}cos(t)dt = \int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{e^{(z-1)ln(t)}(e^{-it}+e^{it})}{2}dt$$

$$\int^{\infty}_{0}\ t^{z-1}sin(t)dt = \int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{e^{(z-1)ln(t)}(ie^{-it}-ie^{it})}{2}dt$$

and then trying to bound the real component, but I haven't been able to make much progress. Any help in the right direction would greatly appreciated!

Comment: As an aside, using the integral expression for the [$\Gamma$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) in conjunction with [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula), for $\Re(z)\in(0,1)$, we have $I_1=\Gamma(z)\cos\bigg(z~\dfrac\pi2\bigg)$ and $I_2=\Gamma(z)\sin\bigg(z~\dfrac\pi2\bigg)$, respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first integral,

1) First show that $\displaystyle \int_0^1 t^{z-1}\cos(t)dt$ is convergent (we have $|t^{z-1}\cos(t)|\leq t^{x-1}$, ($ {\rm Re}(z)=x$).

2) Let $A>1$. Integrate by parts $\displaystyle \int_1^A t^{z-1}\cos(t)dt$, (integrate $\cos(t)$), and show that the integrated part has a limit as $A\to +\infty$, and that the remaining integral is (absolutely) convergent on $[1,+\infty[$.

3) Same method for the second integral.

Comment: How can we show that the integral in your first step is convergent (i.e. how do we know that the integral of t^(x-1) dt from 0 to 1 is convergent for 0<x<1)?

Comment: For $0<y<1$, you have $\int_y^1 t^{x-1}dt=\frac{1-y^x}{x}$, and as $x>0$, this has a limit as $y\to 0$.

Comment: That makes sense - why is the domain of convergence -1<Re(z)<1 for the sine integral though?

Comment: Because you can write $\sin(t)=t\frac{\sin(t)}{t}=tg(t)$, and putting $g(0)=1$, the function $g$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ (hence bounded on $[0,1]$). So in the second integral, you have a $t^{x}$ instead of a $t^{x-1}$ (for the integral between $0$ and $1$).